# Make a custom observer fire before an existing Magento observer

Tags: magento

Is there a way to make an observer that you have custom made have higher priority than the Magento one that fires on the same event. My problem is I am modifying the output of the Welcome block but the PageCache for enterprise fires on the same corecore_block_abstract_to_html_after event.

I tried putting this in my config but it didn't work like cron jobs do.

```
<core_block_abstract_to_html_after>
                <observers>
                    <modify_welcome>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>groupname_page/observer</class>
                        <method>changeWelcomeText</method>
                    </modify_welcome>
                    <enterprise_pagecache>
                        <class>enterprise_pagecache/observer</class>
                        <method>renderBlockPlaceholder</method>
                    </enterprise_pagecache>
                </observers>
 </core_block_abstract_to_html_after>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

/app/etc/modules/Groupname_Page.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Groupname_Page>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <!-- Your dependencies go here -->
            </depends>
        </Groupname_Page>
        <Enterprise_PageCache>
            <depends>
                <Groupname_Page />
            </depends>
        </Enterprise_PageCache>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: this is on the certification exams

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to control order of observers.
If you take a look on the `Mage_Core_Model_App::dispatchEvent()` method, you'll see how Magento get all observers for a given event from config.xml files and fires them one by one.

Rewriting the Welcome block will help you.

Comment: This isn't strictly true.  If your module loads prior to the module containing the observer you want to jump in front of, your observer will fire first.  This can be done by adding a <depends> block to your modules config file in /app/etc/modules.  The trick is to add the depends block for the module you want to be in front of and have that module depend on your module.

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right. I was not smart enough 6 months ago :)

Comment: Haha, we all learn over time.  Perhaps I wouldn't have known the answer 6 months ago either.

Answer (score 0):

another option is to disable the enterprise cache observer and in your own observer run the method that would have been executed by the disabled observer

In your module's config.xml:

```
        <core_block_abstract_to_html_after>
            <observers>
                <modify_welcome>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>groupname_page/observer</class>
                    <method>changeWelcomeText</method>
                </modify_welcome>
                <enterprise_pagecache>
                    <type>disabled</type>
                </enterprise_pagecache>
            </observers>
        </core_block_abstract_to_html_after>
```

And in your `Observer.php`:

```
    public function changeWelcomeText(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        //do the stuff you want your observer to do first
        //and after it's done, call the Enterprise observer's method
        Mage::getSingleton('enterprise_pagecache/observer')->renderBlockPlaceholder($observer);
    }
```

HTH

Comment: This is tightly coupling your code with the Enterprise_PageCache module where the config method is not.  If you were to wrap that call in a check for the module then you would be less coupled obviously.

Comment: @LeeSaferite you're right, this is not ready to ship code, just a suggestion on how to deal with the OP's issue. There is certainly room for improvement.